# Is `qsort()` really QuickSort?

Tags: c, sorting

Silly question perhaps, but is there any guarantee that the `qsort()` routine in the C standard library really implements the QuickSort algorithm?

Comment: No, and in fact only very bad implementations will implement it as quicksort. The naive quicksort has stack overflow problems, which are easily fixed, but even then it has O(n²) run time. The most advanced implementation is called "introsort" and starts out with a proper (non-naive) quicksort but detects worst-case runtime and switches to heapsort (or any other O(n log n) sort would work) in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Since there is nothing in the standard that nominates QuickSort specifically, no.